# Adjust size and gap between FancyButton placed on LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have placed programmatically generated [FancyButtons](https://github.com/medyo/fancybuttons) on LinearLayout. But, the generated buttons are placed too compactly, in other words, there is no separation between two successive buttons. Also, I want the buttons to stretch entire with of the layout. I tried `btnWordList.setMinimumWidth(MATCH_PARENT)` without any result. Please find the code below.

**FlexDict.java**

```
package in.dipanjan.flexdict;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class FlexDict extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        int listCount, wordLists = 5;

        /* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078461/android-null-pointer-exception-findviewbyid */
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_flex_dict);
        LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

        for(listCount = 1; listCount <= wordLists; listCount++)
        {
            /* https://github.com/medyo/fancybuttons */
            FancyButton btnWordList = new FancyButton(this);
            btnWordList.setId(listCount);
            btnWordList.setText("WordList " + listCount);
            btnWordList.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3b5998"));
            btnWordList.setFocusBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5474b8"));
            btnWordList.setTextSize(20);
            btnWordList.setIconResource("\uf04b");
            btnWordList.setRadius(10);
            btnWordList.setOnClickListener(this);
            container.addView(btnWordList);
        }

        setContentView(container);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int wordList = view.getId();

        /*
        * http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1525
        * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980627/pressing-back-button-did-not-go-back-to-previous-activity-android
        */
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putInt("WordList", wordList);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowList.class);
        intent.putExtras(params);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**activity_flex_dict.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/radialback">
</LinearLayout>
```

UI

http://s26.postimg.org/rkb0r4ys9/Fancy_Button.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `setLayoutParams` on your `View`.

i.e. `btnWordList.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT));`

You need to set layout params for any view even if instantiated in XML or Programatically.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)

> Set the layout parameters associated with this view. These supply parameters to the parent of this view specifying how it should be arranged. There are many subclasses of ViewGroup.LayoutParams, and these correspond to the different subclasses of ViewGroup that are responsible for arranging their children.

Comment: But now the problem is that the text is automatically right-aligned. I tried `btnWordList.setTextAlignment(FancyButton.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);`, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: look into `View.Gravity`

Comment: `lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER`  or `btnWordList.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)` doesn't work either.

Comment: you need to combine, Gravity, LayoutGravity and View width / height (http://www.slideshare.net/PaulBlundell2/android-jam-week-7-udacity-lesson-5-rich-responsive-layouts-manchester slide 12)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a margin between your buttons to make a gab between your buttons. and set your width to match_parent to make the button stretch to the width of the layout

```
int marginBottom = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
    5, 
    r.getDisplayMetrics()
 );

for(listCount = 1; listCount <= wordLists; listCount++)
{
      /* https://github.com/medyo/fancybuttons */
      FancyButton btnWordList = new FancyButton(this);
      btnWordList.setId(listCount);
      LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,      
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
      );
      params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, marginBottom);
      btnWordList.setLayoutParams(params);
      btnWordList.setText("WordList " + listCount);
      btnWordList.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3b5998"));
      btnWordList.setFocusBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5474b8"));
      btnWordList.setTextSize(20);
      btnWordList.setIconResource("\uf04b");
      btnWordList.setRadius(10);
      btnWordList.setOnClickListener(this);
      container.addView(btnWordList);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LayoutParam` with margin

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.bottumMargin = 2;
```

// or
lp.setMargins(0,0,0,2);

```
btnWordList.setLayoutParams(lp);
```